# Spotify + Facebook integration - Hitting the pause button on Facebook pauses my native mac client almost instantaneously. How is this done?

Tags: facebook, spotify

Just as the question reads. If I goto my FB Activity, it shows the track that's being played and a pause button. If I hit "Pause" it pauses my native spotify app instantaneously. How is this implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript on Facebook's site submits a request to a web service hosted by Spotify. I do believe that Spotify's client-side application maintains a connection with Spotify's servers. Spotify is able to push content to the user without the client making a request for it, so this web service seems to do this. From my research, I can't find that developing similar functionality is feasible via any API method, whether from Spotify or Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Spotify embeds a web server with a remote control API that Facebook uses directly.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Spotify have a special partnership.  This type of integration is not currently available to other developers.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking to build a Facebook app that does this myself. I just wanted to know how this sort of integration can be built in general terms. One guess is that the Spotify client maintains an open socket with Spotify servers and click on FB notification will message the Spotify servers which in turn notifies the client app. But it seems way too fast for all that to happen.